# why is IIFE needed to create a new scope?

Tags: javascript, closures, lexical-scope

From [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#loops--closure):

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        console.log( i );
    }, i*1000 );
}
```

gives

```
6
6
6
6
6
```

but using an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) like so

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    (function(){
        var j = i;
        setTimeout( function timer(){
            console.log( j );
        }, j*1000 );
    })();
}
```

gives

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

My question: why doesn't

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        var j = i;
        console.log( j );
    }, i*1000 );
}
```

or

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    function timer() {
        var j = i;
        console.log(j);
    }
    setTimeout(timer, i*1000 );
}
```

work like the IIFE example? It seems to me they both have a `function` declaration with a new variable `j`, wouldn't that create a new lexical scope with a specific setting for `i`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important part of the IIFE is that it runs *right away*; before `i` changes, it reads its value and puts it in a new variable. The function reading `i` in your other examples – `function timer()` – does not run right away, and the value it puts in its new variable is the value of `i` after it’s already changed.

Also, in ES6, you can just `let i = …` instead of `var i = …` and it’ll work fine without the IIFE or `j`:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function timer() {
        console.log(i);
    }, i * 1000);
}
```

because `let` has block scope instead of function scope and variables declared in the initialization part of `for` loops count as being half-inside the `for`’s block.

Comment: I think introducing `let` at this point of time will makes him skip away from understanding the fundamental concept. :p

Comment: @Isaac: If you never use `var`, skipping it’s probably fine =P

Comment: seems to me like `let` is definitely the way to go, but `var` is good for understanding certain details

Answer (score 1):

`i`, being declared with `var`, is hoisted. Variables don't automatically get their scopes bound to an inner function; unless the inner function explicitly has `var i` or a paramter of `i` (thus defining a new `i` *bound to the scope of the inner function*), `i` will continue to refer to the hoisted `i` in the outer scope.

For example, you could do what you were thinking of like this, if you wanted:

```js
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(i){
        console.log( i );
    }, i*1000, i );
}
```

(The third argument to `setTimeout` is what the function, the second argument, will be called with)

This means that `timer` will be called with `i` *as it is during iteration*, and the function will use a *new* `i`, bound to the scope of the function, initialized via the parameter.

It's a pretty bad idea, though - better to use `const` and `let`, which have block scope rather than function scope, and better not to shadow outer variables.

Comment: I don’t think this explanation really works, unless the OP thought named functions would work differently than anonymous ones.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of IIFE

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    (function(){
        var j = i;
        setTimeout( function timer(){
            console.log( j );
        }, j*1000 );
    })();
}
```

is often written like

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    (function(j){
        setTimeout( function timer(){
            console.log( j );
        }, j*1000 );
    })(i);
}
```

so, you can see that "captured" value is `i` in this case

You can do the same without IIFE

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    function timer(j) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(j);
        }, j * 1000 );
    }
    timer(i);
}
```

of course, this is equivalent of

```
function timer(j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(j);
    }, j * 1000 );
}

for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    timer(i);
}
```

if using ES2015+, you can use `let`

```
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        console.log( i );
    }, i*1000 );
}
```

Now, if you use a transpiler because you need to support ES5 (or whatever internet exploder supports) you'll see that the transpiled version is

```
var _loop = function _loop(i) {
    setTimeout(function timer() {
        console.log(i);
    }, i * 1000);
};

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    _loop(i);
}
```

Which looks incredibly like the previous version of the code