# immediately-invoked function calling setTimeout calling for loop

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

In the following scenario, event `setTimeout` get queued and only after stack clears out, i = 3 will print 3 times

```js
//ver1
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++ ) setTimeout(()=> console.log(i), 3)
```

The following will print `1 2 3` in order since `i` is captured in `func` x ??

```js
//ver2
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function x(i) {
        setTimeout(() => {console.log(i)}, 30)
    })(i);
}
```

Why the following only prints `2` one time?

```js
//ver3
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    function x(i) {
        setTimeout(() => {console.log(i)}, 30)
    }(i);
}
```

I'm mostly confused between `ver2` and `ver3`

---

EDIT: 
`ver2` explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44059386/7687062). Any insight on why `ver3` only prints `2`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript here you can find answers for your questions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615610/why-is-iife-needed-to-create-a-new-scope here is even a better explanation of what is happening in your code

Comment: but that doesn't explain the behavior of `ver3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version 3 doesn't do at all what you think it does. [Parenthesis are not optional on an IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634268/explain-javascripts-encapsulated-anonymous-function-syntax). But because you named the function, it does get parsed as a function declaration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    function x(i) {
        setTimeout(() => {console.log(i)}, 30)
    }
    (i);
}
```

You were never calling `x(…)` here. The `(i)` is just an unnecessarily-[parenthesised](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) expression evaluating the `i` variable. Your code executes the same as

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    i;
}
```

So why does this log `2` in the console? Because when you run this on the console, it prints the result value of the statement that was evaluated last: `i`, which had the value `2` in the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense..Thanks!